# Dudas con un formulario de creación de cursos en PHP - MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, jquery

Acudo a ustedes con la siguiente consulta,

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño sistema de ingreso e inscripción de cursos, donde habrá 2 tipos de usuarios, los que puedan inscribirse a alguno de los cursos disponibles, y los que además de inscribirse a un curso, puedan crear uno,
Hasta ahora tengo una demo, la cual estoy corriendo de manera local (con EasyPHP), usando un template html5, y en la ventana de “creación de curso”, le solicito al usuario los siguientes datos:

•   Nombre del curso
•   Fecha de realización
•   Cantidad de horas
•   Código SIGPER (un código legal, el cual no es obligatorio)
•   Cantidad de vacantes
•   Ubicación física del curso
•   Ámbito del curso
•   Escoja un relator

Mi formulario de creación de cursos es así,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo de “Escoja un relator”, tengo un combobox desde donde realiza la consulta sql a una tabla denominada “relatores”, con la siguiente estructura,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y una vez que se completa el formulario, los datos del cursos se guardan en una tabla llamada “cursos”, con la siguiente estructura,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, en la última reunión, me solicitaron algunos cambios, y entre ellos, que el usuario fuera capaz de ingresar el relator y su ámbito, no seleccionarlo desde una base de datos predefinida.

El problema está en que también quieren  que se ingrese más de un relator al curso, básicamente, que el usuario elija cuantos relatores ingresar, y que se dé la posibilidad de entregar reportes sobre la cantidad de relatores y los cursos de cada uno.

He buscado algunos efectos para agregar dinámicamente cajas de texto con javascript, pero me generan las siguientes dudas:

- Como hacer para que se guarde el dato del relator en ambas tablas, considerando que en la tabla “cursos” se agregara el dato “id_relator” a la vez que el relator nuevo se está agregando junto a su ámbito en la tabla “relatores"
- Como hacer para verificar que el usuario no agregue 2 veces el mismo relator, o si el nombre del relator ya está en la base de datos, que no se vuelva a repetir

Si alguien tiene una mejor idea de cómo agregar relatores en el formulario, bienvenido sea, o si no me exprese bien en algún punto me avisan,

De antemano, muchísimas gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si un curso puede tener mas de 1 relator en ese caso el id del curso debes pasarlo a la tabla id_relator, en esa tabla necesitas establecer 2 laves primarias para que no se pueda repetir un relator al mismo curso.

Comment: En este caso, un relator puede tener mas de 1 curso, no es exclusivo de solo un curso